# Separation of LSTM weights

Tags: tensorflow

On running the following lines of code within a session

```
variables =[v for v in tf.trainable_variables()]
values = session.run(variables)
```

I am able to obtain all the trainable weights and biases in the deep RNN I have defined in my graph. The LSTM weights however are clumped together, meaning the forget, input, cell and output gate weights for both x<sub>t</sub> and h<sub>t-1</sub> are returned as one large matrix. I would like to know which part of the matrix refers to which weight matrix.

An example being if I defined the inputs to a RNN layer to be 240 and there are 512 cells in the layer, the returned weights would be of size `752x2048`. From looking at the codes on GitHub I believe they can be separated as

W<sub>xi</sub>W<sub>xj</sub>W<sub>xf</sub>W<sub>xo</sub>

W<sub>hi</sub>W<sub>hj</sub>W<sub>hf</sub>W<sub>ho</sub>

Where all weights corresponding to inputs from the previous layer (W<sub>x</sub>) are placed on top, one beside another and inputs from the same layer and previous time-step (W<sub>h</sub>) are placed below, one beside another. Therefore the weights W<sub>x</sub> occupy the locations `W[0:239, 0:2047]` and W<sub>h</sub> occupy the locations `W[240:751, 0:2047]`. Also the size of all W<sub>x_</sub> will be of size `240x512` and W<sub>h_</sub> will be of size `512x512`. Please let me know if I am correct, if not, please describe the correct configuration.

Comment: are you using RNNCells or are are you cells user defined?

Comment: I am using LSTMCells defined in Tensorflow, the contrib/rnn folder definition to be exact.

Comment: @Deepak Kadetotad: Did you figure out the structure of the weights?

Comment: This is from the documentation of tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py
Look at the line 641. You are correct.